# how to make a link in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display click here to see the article in javascript.

```
$('.rrssb-buttons').rrssb({
    // required:
    title: '{{post.title}}',
    url: window.location.href,

    // optional:
    description: '{{post.content.strip|safe}}',
    emailBody: window.location.href 
  });
```

so the above is my code, and inside emailBody it currently shows the correct url.
I want this url to be in a tag. and on screen this play as click here to see the article. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I am interpreting your question correctly, you wish to have the content of an email address show a link to the article. For example,

> [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com) to see the article.

A simple concatenation into an HTML element should display in the email correctly if the email is not viewed as plain text.

```
$('.rrssb-buttons').rrssb({
    // required:
    title: '{{post.title}}',
    url: window.location.href,

    // optional:
    description: '{{post.content.strip|safe}}',
    emailBody: '<a href=" + window.location.href + '">Click here</a> to see the article.'
});
```